# JOIN Table request to retrieve all rooms that are not already booked in the time period requested

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app with a `room` model that has_many `bookings`.
My booking table has a `room_id`, a `start_date`, a `end_date`.

In my form, I ask my user for the time period he wishes to book the room for : `params[:from], params[:to]`

I need to retrieve all the rooms from the db that are not booked for the time period requested. I think that this request can be represented by the intersection of two groups :
A)  All rooms that dont have a booking with a `start_date` between `params[:from]` and `params[:to]`
B) All rooms that dont have a booking with a `end_date`between `params[:from]` and `params[:to]`
C) All rooms that dont have a booking with a start_date prior to `params[:from]` and after `params[:to]`

I came up with this

```
Room.joins(:bookings).where("bookings.start_date >= ? AND <= ?", params[:from], params[:to])
```

but this is only answering partially the problem. How can I write an AR request (SQL or AR) that will retrieve all rooms that are not booked in the time period requested.

Comment: why you post this question on different account ??

Comment: how do you calculated already booked room?

Comment: Can you please add your models or at least the relations? Also the schema would be nice

Comment: @max I just did that

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ There's a table bookings in my db, this table has a room_id and a start_date and end_date